# declaring array of an object X with unknown size objective c

Tags: objective-c

How would I go about declaring an array in the .h file of an unknown size that I will calculate say in the a function inside the class ?

For example, I might have 20 or 30 NSArrays (just an example, not what I need), but I won't know the exact number when the class is first called

in implementation file..

```
-(id) init {
   if self = ..
       number_of_arrays = 50; // this can be whatever value
}
```

in .h:

```
int number_of_arrays;
NSArray *arrays_of_unknown_size[number_of_arrays]; // but number of arrays is not init !
```

---

Also, what is the significance of NSArray **arrays ? Would I be able to declare that in the h file, and then in the .m file, declare the actual size ?

thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two choices.

1) Make it an NSArray of NSArrays, or

2) Declare it as:

```
NSArray **arrays_of_unknown_size;
```

Then you can malloc/calloc the pointer when you know the actual size. Then you need to assign an NSArray to each element of the C-array.

Answer (score 2):

Like rmaddy says, you can just allocate the array with malloc:

```
arrays_of_unknown_size= (NSArray**)malloc(N*sizeof(NSArray*));
```

You can also reallocate it with realloc, and the size may change.
Another way is to use an array containing an array:

```
NSMutableArray* array_of_unknown_size=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

Then when the array is already populated, get the single array that you want:

```
NSArray* myArray=[array_of_unknown_size objectAtIndex: myIndex];
```

Of course arrays_of_unknown_size is too long, don't use this name, it's just an example.